# Importing a SQL database using CMD - unique access is denied error

Tags: mysql, database, cmd, mariadb

I've been trying to import a database using CMD but it's not working.

I can connect to the database and use commands like:

```
SHOW_DATABASES;
```

but whenever I try to import my database it just gives me the error "access is denied"

This is the command I'm using:

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin>mysql -u {username} -p {database_name} < {filepath to .sql}
```

I've tried to create a new user in phpMyAdmin and import the database that way but I still get the same error...

I can't see the issue, it seems my usernames and ps are correct, I'm connecting to the database, I have all privileges on the db user accounts and my command line is correct.

Any ideas on what the issue could be.

Final note - When I connect to the db it says I'm connected to a MariaDB:

```
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 184
Server version: 10.1.24-MariaDB mariadb.org binary distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2017, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.
```

Comment: Have you tried this using the Super User account? i.e. `root`

Comment: I would suggest you carefully check the privileges that the user account you are using has been granted

Comment: Yes I've tried using root

Comment: Well if `root` cannot do it, then that is serious!!! Maybe you had better check what is in the `.sql` file.

Comment: @RiggsFolly when I look at the users in phpMyAdmin it says the uses I'm using have all privileges

Comment: Okay, the sql file was download from my website, what should I be looking out for??

Comment: You seemed surprised that MariaDB was being used? Should you be using MariaDB? Was the Export done from a MySQL database?

Comment: Also what version of MySQL was running on the server where you took this export from

Comment: Well, I'm not too sure, someone else built the site originally. I just downloaded it through a wp.engine portal using phpMyAdmin

Comment: Also can you show us the Complete error message without an omitions

Comment: C:\xampp\mysql\bin>mysqldump -umob -p euroloomobile <c:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\euroloodatabase.sql
Access is denied.

Comment: That is all I am getting

Comment: Copy your .sql file into some agnostic folder like `C:\xampp\mysql\bin\euroloodatabase.sql` I think its saying it cannot find the input file. **Probably because `c:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\` does not actually exist** Or is not accessible by the user you are logged in as

Comment: @RiggsFolly Looks like that worked but it seems the tables have not imported. I got this messages in CMD: -- Dump completed on 2017-07-18 11:59:53 But no tables in phpMyAdmin... erughh problem after problem

Comment: Not familiar with recent XAMPP versions. Are you sure you didnt import into MariaDB but are looking at a MySQL Server instance that is also running

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yep it's the same instance, I've tested this by creating a new db in cmd and seeing if it appears in phpMyAdmin, which it does. Thank you for all your help btw, useful information, much appreciated.

Comment: I would be tempted to try copying a small section of the .sql file and pasting it into phpMyAdmin just to see if the sql will create the first table and INSERT some rows into it.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I tried that and that worked... Does this mean there is something wrong with the sql file?

Comment: Possibly. Difficult to tell from here. Have you tried doing an IMPORT in phpMyAdmin. Maybe you might find where abouts in the file you have an issue

Comment: I think the file is too big to go through phpMyAdmin, I've tried to import it but it just gives me a Maximum execution time error. I've tried to config phpMyAdmin to have no limit but it still times out

Comment: edit `php.ini` amend `max_execution_time = 1000`

Comment: Put it back to what it is now once finished

Comment: I have tried setting it to 0 but I'll give that a try now.

Comment: I still go the same error

Comment: Did you restart Apache aftre changing `'php.ini`

Comment: I did but it gave me a session expired error... I'm going to download the database again to see if it corrupted while downloading

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command:

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON databaseName.* TO 'userName'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

this will give your user all permissions. But be warned, that '%' means everything, so any connection could connect. 'localhost' could be a safer alternative. With user accounts, it's best to make accounts with permissions specific to their tasks, e.g. a export/import user for just export and importing data. But if this is 100% local development, it doesn't matter as much - but keep in mind on production servers that this is a risk.

After that you should be able to use the following:

the command to import/export isn't `mysql` it's `mysqldump` -

what you want to do for export:

`mysqldump -uuserName -p databaseName > file.sql`

to import:

`mysqldump -uuserName -p databaseName < file.sql`

or you can access via mysql and use `source` like so:

```
mysql -uuser -p
source /path/to/sql.sql
```

Comment: You should also be able to do what the OP is doing.

Comment: @RiggsFolly that comment threw me a little haha sorry could you explain? :)

Comment: Tried this and I still get the same error "access is denied"

Comment: Assuming OP has not destroyed the root account, having tried this restore with the root account, there must be something else going on here that we are not be told about

Comment: Just a little point: Suggestion that the user account be given Full Root Access and using the `'@'%'` from anywhere option, might be considered a little dangerous, or a major security problem

Comment: @RiggsFolly ah good point - will edit answer to say this would be best done on local only

Comment: I'm just setting up a test environment for my website to redesign a mobile version of the site, how would I restore?

Comment: @DanielYorwarth it might be worth editing your Q with how the mysql server and database was set up :) anything odd during each process?

Comment: Nothing really odd, I'm using xampp, I created a database and then tried to import my dump. tbh I'm not really too familiar and fear the problem might be way above what I can do but I'll keep trying...

Comment: See [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45164127/importing-a-sql-database-using-cmd-unique-access-is-denied-error#comment77297361_45164127)